# Is there a way to connect Android app to Excel data source in oneDrive or Sharepoint?

Tags: java, android

I need to build an App in Android for my colleagues and distributors to collaborate. The datasource will be an Excel file residing in our company's OneDrive or Sharepoint, for which, the users can be given access. I have been looking around but could not find a way to do this with Android/Java. Would appreciate any help I can get from the community!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **[Apache-POI](http://poi.apache.org/)** Java API for reading Excel File.
it's plain but still the best solution for that now.

However, if you just need to read the Excel, it maybe good to go with JavaScript solution. With [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx) library, you can transfer Excel files into JSON. And the library size is small, just 395KB (only include xlsx.core.min.js)

to connect your application with one drive , use [OneDriveSdkAndroid](https://github.com/OneDrive/onedrive-sdk-android)

Comment: I think OP wants to know, how to connect with OneDrive or Sharepoint.

Comment: Thanks Ismail. I am currently exploring these options you recommended.